# Shortest path in a dag but must go through m type-A edges and n type-B edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

There is a dag (directed acyclic graph) with a weight on each edge, and each edge has a type, either type-A or type-B

For example:

[image: Imgur]

(red edges mean type-A, and black edges mean type-B edges)

The problem is defined as following:

```
given two vertices s, t, find a shortest path between these two vertices
subject to the usage of m type-A edges and n type-B edges,
or report no such path exists
```

e.g., Given A, D and m = 1, n = 2, find the shortest path between A and D and meanwhile meet the constraint

in this case, the shortest path is A, B, C, D and the shortest path length is 7

One idea had popped on my head, first, we do the topological sort, 
then using the topological order as a examination sequence, keep tracking the shortest path length and the traversed edges starting from A

The bookkeeping record will look like this,

[**Number_of_Type_A**, **Number_of_Type_B**, **Shortest_length**, **Predecessor**]

and keep considering the incoming edge just like the usual way to find a shortest path in a dag

e.g.

[image: Imgur]

(I missed a 3 on the edge (B,D) )

consider A:

```
[0, 0, 0, NIL]
```

consider B: (1 incoming edge)

```
[1, 0, 1, A]
```

consider C: (2 incoming edge)

```
[1, 1, 3, B] and 
[1, 0, 1, A]
```

consider D: (2 incoming edge)

```
[1, 2, 7, C] and
[1, 1, 5, C] and 
[2, 0, 4, B]
```

Since there is a path using 1 type-A and 2 type-B edges, and the shortest path and length can be found on the record and tracking back the predecessors

so this is it.

( The time complexity is...O(V+E)? I think maybe bigger than this, but I have no idea how to analyse it)

I am not sure this is a right way to solve this problem.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? and what is this problem called in general?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your solution is pretty good! (Isn't it good enough?) By the way, I think the time complexity is O(m*n*(V+E))

Comment: Your solution is basically Bellman-Ford with two more dimensions (m,n) - but since this is a DAG, we do not need to revisit vertices and edges, so as said - it seems like O(m*n*(V+E)). Note that if your graph was not a DAG, unless I miss something - you could follow the same approach to get O(m*n*V*E), for general graph.

Comment: Actually, I did not get it why O(m*n*(V+E)), and I don' think the time needed for general case can be done in O(m*n*(V+E)) either. Would any one give any more specific explanation and the correctness of this algorithm? And furthermore, i just think the space requirement is intimidating, so I try to figure out is there any way to improve it or what. Thanks a bunch!